# How to download a file using JS being the file a result from an action method (.NET Core 2 MVC)

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a controller action method that returns a file for download.
I need to call this action method via Jquery, so, how do I get the file for download?

I know how to call the action method via Ajax call or window.location, but since the action method result is a file, how do I put it for the user to download via JQuery?

Here is my action method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportClientes()
    {
        var model = new BasesDadosViewModel();

        model.Clientes = await _db.Clientes.ToListAsync();
        model.ClienteObj = new Clientes();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        List<string> DontUse_Field = typeof(Clientes).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ObjAttributes), true).Any(ca => ((ObjAttributes)ca).DontUse)).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        var cliente_fields = model.ClienteObj.GetType().GetProperties();

        //formatar colunas da datatable
        foreach (var field in cliente_fields)
        {
            DataColumn col = dt.Columns.Add(field.Name, field.PropertyType);
        }

        foreach (var cliente in model.Clientes)
        {
            DataRow export_row = dt.NewRow();

            //Preenche dados
            int c = 0;
            foreach (var field in cliente_fields)
            {
                if (!DontUse_Field.Contains(field.Name))
                {
                    export_row[c] = field.GetValue(cliente);
                    c++;
                }

            }

            dt.Rows.Add(export_row);
        }

        ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage();
        var workSheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Clientes_Export");

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[1, i].Value = dt.Columns[i - 1];
        }

        int index = 2;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[index, i].Value = row[i - 1];
            }

            index++;
        }

        //Autofit columns
        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Column(i).AutoFit();
        }

        var filename = "Clientes_Export.xlsx";
        //var path = Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"exports", filename);
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            excel.SaveAs(fileStream);
        }


        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memory);
        }

        memory.Position = 0;
        ContentTypes contentType = new ContentTypes();
        return File(memory, contentType.GetContentType(filename), filename);

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/url/for/file',
    method: 'GET',
    xhrFields:{
        responseType: 'blob'
    },
    success: function (data) {
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        a.download = 'filename.ext';
        document.body.append(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

To summarize, you need to use the `$.ajax` call (instead of something like `$.get`) so you can pass options. One of those options needs to be `xhrFields` so you can specify a response type of `blob`. Then, inside your success function, you'll dynamically create a new `a` element, set the `download` attribute to the filename + extension you want the file to be downloaded as, set the `href` attribute with an object URL (composed from the blob data), and then append this element to your body. After that, it's a simple matter of triggering a click event on this dynamically created element.

Comment: Hi Chris,
First of all, thank you very much for helping me. However, your suggestion is not working. maybe because of my action method?

I updated my question with the action method.

Thank you